# Arrays as inputs to custom functions causing the add-in to fail loading

Tags: javascript, typescript, office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

I am trying to write custom functions for Excel which take arrays (i.e. a range of cells) as input and return either a value or an array.

Here's an example from my `function.ts` file:

```
/* global clearInterval, console, CustomFunctions, setInterval */

// OTHER FUNCTIONS

/**
 * Percent bias
 * @customfunction
 * @param Observed Observed Data
 * @param Simulated Simulated Data
 * @returns Percent bias
 */
function PBias(Observed: number[], Simulated: number[]): number {
  let sum_obs = Observed.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
  let sum_sim = Simulated.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);

  return (100 * (sum_sim - sum_obs)) / sum_obs;
}
}
```

This gets built with no issues, but when I start debugging, I get an error which says my custom functions were not loaded.

If I take `PBias` out, other functions do get loaded and work properly.

Those functions seems to work as intended: [TS playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUgFBTATgY3gOwC6QEYEsCGAzlDAALICuhGA9gLYBmFayGuNaJkpADvovjqQA8tkJIAbvAAmIsZJmQAIvgz4uvfoMgBlXHQoAbVYr0HjGRSrUbE8DBURpCcJKkw4CxaMHBMWbBxwAEJeABSi4ohS0gBckGgUdNhIANoAugA0uvpGJnEJSSmIGQCU8YnJSJAA3lCQhvaQhEkA+jRikAC8clExAHR20hSoYWF8iGz4hjpJ2fil3QB8kBNTM0mQANSQ+NkADKUA3PWNWC10rYT63Tnm+YMyI-BjawQbdPOLXStv07NCHZ7SCHE71OwOJyQMIARn2+2g0IuVxuAFpmm0OoRSotgBjLliTgBfcCks6QLE9SCpGGZABMmQAzJkACyZACs6RO5OuQh6qQZkGZQv67OybMgnLByA4hBojX6hhoAHMwrBQkQwljsrycWDQBBEQBVNA8XASGgYFz4SACNDK+AUhiQVCGQyEfoaSjUej+VjsTiIzQCIQAC3g+GkSBcABVw7b8PbHTRna73ZAMKHVLb4Dw7OIPABPGiOSDhyPRz1BibaRA0ADusfjdodTpd8DdLkz2bsefgBawxdLdfrZYjUcQHo0NaEEmmFH7kDjjpbydTHfT3awvfz6EHJcQCaTbbnhgXU6DEMczkgS-jaBoiDo01wAC9FKu22mLyBfH7AmgkDMGaFoYGE5YToQ8SJoWGTZCOUG7GgsFZJAp7ntByEZGUmEoRktSnE0wHmparTSKoNr8ly9QMI+0JzoeI63PsRy2g2kAADxsY2iroMqmasSOWxbIsdS3retGHmEDFjhWh49CxskTpxSmVo09oCapiDCaJ9TiUBpokRgZEUf0PBUKGYSpAh1kNqhEHRqkDmIKh6H9rZ9bpE545IOk6THHpkAkreJLgvY14GSBpHkWoxJkk0uCyPyABEACCyXZMlwQZZAyUAMI5clSjJdR5KFvJ1LJXS8L7IV1X7DCdXwnSJXck0p63KkNL0kyqGpGyYoAGx9QA7JkAAcmQAJx9XCmQwrSMJ0n50qyvK8CKiqYTEaBYTldkiXZKeepAA)

I have tried this with a fresh install of Node.js (version 18.18.0), and Yeoman Generator for Office Add-ins (version 4.3.1, using Excel Custom Functions with a Shared Runtime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out or at least find a workaround. It seems that ranges are considered 2D arrays. So, inputs should be defined as `any[][]`. I think this is a recent change (or a bug) introduced in the recent version of Yeoman, since I have seen online tutorials using `number[]` or `any[]` as input. In any case, this variation of my function gets loaded and works properly.

Here, I flatten the arrays prior to my calculations.

```
/**
 * Percent bias
 * @customfunction
 * @param Observed Observed Data
 * @param Simulated Simulated Data
 * @returns Percent bias
 */
export function PBias(Observed: number[][], Simulated: number[][]): number {
  let sum_obs = 0;
  let sum_sim = 0;

  sum_obs = Observed.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  }) // flatten array
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }); // sum

  sum_sim = Simulated.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  }) // flatten array
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }); // sum

  return (100 * (sum_sim - sum_obs)) / sum_obs;
}
```

I am still interested to see if there is a better approach or a clearer explanation for this.

Answer (score 2):

As you have managed to find, you should use 2D array `number[][]` if you hope to take a range as input. That is because any range with more than 1 cell is considered as a 2D array (1 single cell can also be treated as 2D array like "[[A1]]").

This may not be a recent regression of Yeoman. Here is the public document about 1D, 2D and 3D arrays as parameters of custom functions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-parameter-options?tabs=javascript#repeating-single-value-parameter.
In short: 1D array for repeating single values, 2D array for range, 3D array for repeating ranges.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I actually figured it out by reading that exact same part of documentation. But I think this is a change that happened in the last couple of years (I know for a fact that this https://github.com/areed1192/excel-custom-function-add-in/blob/master/src/functions/functions.ts code used to work for me).